# Error calculating CRC16 for certain characters in C

Tags: c, crc16

I am trying to use this code to compute CRC16 bypass. For regular characters it works but for a hex sequence like `0xA0 0x00 0x01 0x01` it fails, not returning the correct value. Go easy on me, usually I do not write C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned short CalculateCRC(unsigned char* a_szBuffuer, short a_sBufferLen){
    unsigned short usCRC = 0;
    for (short j = 0; j < a_sBufferLen; j++)
    {
    unsigned char* pucPtr = (unsigned char *)&usCRC;
    *(pucPtr + 1) = *(pucPtr + 1) ^ *a_szBuffuer++;
    for (short i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
    if (usCRC & ((unsigned short) 0x8000))
    {
    usCRC = usCRC << 1;
    usCRC = usCRC ^ ((unsigned short) 0x8005);
    }
    else
    usCRC = usCRC << 1;
    }
    }
    return (usCRC);
}

void append(char* s, char c)
{
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int main() {

   char d = (char)0xA0;
   char d1 = (char)0x00;
   char d2 = (char)0x01;
   char d3 = (char)0x01;
   char sss[256]="";

   append(sss, d);
   append(sss, d1);
   append(sss, d2);
   append(sss, d3);
   unsigned char* uCB1 = (unsigned char*)sss;
   unsigned short CRC= CalculateCRC(uCB1,4);

   printf("CRC = %i\n", CRC);
   printf("%s\n", sss);
   printf("%x\n", CRC);
}
```

Comment: You can't have characters with code `0x00` in something you manipulate as a string (using `strlen` on it in particular)

Comment: Yup, it's a fundamental of C that strings are `\0`-terminated. Binary data is not a string - or phrased differently, strings are strings, not general-purpose series of bytes. Out of interest, how else did you think `strlen()` and friends would know where your string ends?

Comment: Please indent the code properly, doubly so if you are new to C.

Comment: How is the returned value incorrect. Please give sample input, output, desired output.

Comment: Probably not the real problem, but that pucPtr manipulation is not portable (depends on endianness), and might completely fail to work with an optimizing compiler that follows strict aliasing rules. Just use bit shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strlen(s);` is for finding the *length* of a *string*, not for finding the length of a character array that is used,  especially if it that may contain `'\0'`.  [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266708/error-calculating-crc16-for-certain-characters-in-c/48267295#comment83516536_48266708)

Code needs to keep track of the array size used with another variable.

```
// void append(char* s, char c) {
void append(char* s, size_t *sz, char c) {
  s[*sz] = c;
  (*sz)++;
}

...
size_t size = 0;
append(sss, &size, d);
append(sss, &size, d1);
append(sss, &size, d2);
append(sss, &size, d3);
unsigned char* uCB1 = (unsigned char*)sss;
unsigned short CRC= CalculateCRC(uCB1, size);

// printf("%s\n", sss);
write a loop to print each `sss[]`.
```